# Hierarchy of && and ||

Tags: if-statement

Let's say I have this code (bool1, bool2 and bool3 are booleans [should be obvious)):

```
if (bool1 && bool2 || bool3)
```

When is this if-Statement true? So what if only bool3 is true and the other two booleans are false. So I want to know if it is equal to

```
if ((bool1 && bool2) || bool3)
```

or

```
if (bool1 && (bool2 || bool3))
```

I know I can simply put some more brackets in there, but my code would be shorter if not.

Comment: Learn how to create logic truth tables and map it out, its very easy. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check operator's precedence table for your language. For C++ it is:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

```
13  &&   Logical AND
14  ||   Logical OR
```

`bool1 && bool2 || bool3` is `(bool1 && bool2) || bool3`

It is not about `if-statement` it is about evaluating boolean expressions.